# Open File in Modal Dialogue

Tags: java, file, modal-dialog, response

I have this code for open any file from a path. But in this case, the file is opened in a new tab.

I need that response open this file in a modal bootstrap or a dialogue.

```
File file = new File(path);
String name = file.getName();
int fileSize = (int) file.length();
response.setContentType(contentType);
response.setContentLength(sizeFile);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
output = response.getOutputStream();
Files.copy(file.toPath(), output);
```

Someone has a tip or other method to do?

Comment: So basically you want to "preview" the file in a modal window on your browser, just like google drive does for example? What kind of file is it?

Comment: Yes. Can be PDF, docx, xlsx for example.

Comment: Well I suppose directing the response to an iframe inside a modal dialog could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Using bootstrap 3.3.5

In the HTML a button calls a javascript function 'view' passing as parameters the path to servlet (MSD) and the extension of file:

```
<button class="btn-doc-sm btn-default" type="button" 
    onclick="view('<% out.print(MSD?p=c:/upload/documents/document.docx&action=view)); %>', '<% out.print(ext); %>')" id="view">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>View
</button>
```

The .js function set the path's value on modal identifyed by pathDoc and open the 'view' modal.

```
function view(path, ext) {
        var booleanValue;
        if (path !== null) {
            $("#pathDoc").attr("src", path);
            $("#view").modal('show');
            booleanValue = true;
        }
        if (booleanValue !== true) {
            $("#error").modal('show');
        }
    }
```

Modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="view" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Header -->
                    <div id="confirmacao-label1">
                        <a href="#close" title="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="closeModal">X</a>
                    </div>
                        <!-- End header -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3" id="modal-embed">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="pathDoc" nome="pathDoc" src=""></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The 'variable path' is a link to call the servlet passing the 'real path' and the action as a parameter. The servlet will open a output with the file.

```
switch(action){
            case "view":
                try {
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    String name = file.getName();
                    int fileSize = (int) file.length();
                    response.setContentType(action);
                    response.setContentLength(fileSize);
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + name + "\"");
                    output = response.getOutputStream();
                    Files.copy(file.toPath(), output);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex ) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    output.close();
                }
                break;
```

So, when the Modal is called, a link to servlet to open a file is set on src. The servlet search and open the file on output.